# D3 cluster layout design

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i tried to deign a cluster layout in d3.has content in json file..some of the nodes here is a parent node.when i click on the parent node ..it shows the children..i want to close the excisting node ,when i open a new parent node..any idea?

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>

  <head>
    <title>Radial Cluster Demo</title>
    <script src="ddd.js"></script>
    <script src="q.js"></script>
    <style>
      .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }

      text:hover {
        fill: red;
      }

      .node {
        cursor: pointer;
        font: 10px sans-serif;
      }

      .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }

      div#tooltip {
        color: black;
        background: orange;
        //   opacity:1;
        // padding:5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="tooltip" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="viz" class="dd"></div>
    <script>
      var width = $(document).width();
      var height = $(document).height();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var radius = 600 / 2;

      var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
        .size([360, radius - 120])
        // .separation(function (a, b) {
        //  return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 10) / a.depth;
        //});
      var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
        .projection(function(d) {
          return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
        });

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", radius * 2)
        .attr("height", radius * 2)
        //  .attr("width", width *2 )
        //  .attr("height", height*4)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");
      var data = {
        "name": "அகல்",
        "children": [{
          "name": "விலகு",
          "color": "red"
        }, {
          "name": "நீங்கு",
          "color": "red",
          "l": "red",
          "f": "360",
          "t": "நீங்குதல், பாயிருளகல (புறநா.25).",
          "children": [{
            "name": "விலகு",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "பின்னிடு",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "ஒதுங்கு",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "இடம்விட்டுப் பெயர்",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "பிரி",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "பின்வாங்கு",
            "color": "red"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "பிரி",
          "color": "red",
          "t": "பிரிதல். அகன்ற பூங்கொடியை (பாரத.குரு.79)"
        }, {
          "name": "கட",
          "color": "#1E90FF",
          "t": "கடத்தல். (திவா.)"
        }, {
          "name": "விருத்தியடை",
          "color": "green",
          "t": "விருத்தியடைதல் (குறள்,170.)"
        }, {
          "name": "விசாலி",
          "color": "#00C957",
          "t": "விசாலித்தல். (புறநா.3,16.)"
        }, {
          "name": "நீட்டு",
          "color": "#00C957"
        }, {
          "name": "விரி",
          "color": "#00C957"
        }, {
          "name": "பரப்பு",
          "color": "#00C957"
        }, {
          "name": "விரிவு",
          "color": "#00C957"
        }, {
          "name": "விளக்குத் தகழி",
          "color": "#D15FEE",
          "t": "விளக்குத் தகழி. திருவிளக்குத் 
        திரியிட்டங் ககல்பரப்பி (பெரியபு.கலிய.15)."
        }, {
          "name": "சட்டி",
          "color": "orange",
          "l": "red",
          "f": "360",
          "t": "சட்டி. காரகற்கூவியன் (பெரும்பாண். 377)",
          "children": [{
            "name": "மட்பாண்டம்",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "உலோகத்தட்டு",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "திதி",
            "color": "green"
          }, {
            "name": "அறுபது",
            "color": "orange"
          }, {
            "name": "தாமரை",
            "color": "purple"
          }, {
            "name": "அழித்தல்",
            "color": "brown"
          }, {
            "name": "கொல்லுதல்",
            "color": "brown"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "ஓர் அளவு",
          "color": "blue",
          "t": "ஓர் அளவு. (தொல்.எழுத்.170,உரை.)"
        }, {
          "name": "வெள்வேல்",
          "color": "maroon",
          "t": "(சங்.அக.)"
        }, {
          "name": "உள்ளூர்",
          "color": "purple",
          "t": "(பொதி. நி.) "
        }, {
          "name": "ஊரின் உட்புறம்",
          "color": "purple",
          "t": "ஊரின் உட்புறம். (பொதி. நி.)"
        }, {
          "name": "நாடு",
          "color": "brown",
          "l": "red",
          "f": "360",
          "t": "நாடு. (பொதி. நி.)",
          "children": [{
            "name": "தேடு",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "ஆராய்",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "தெரி",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "அள",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "கிட்டு",
            "color": "red"
          }, {
            "name": "விரும்பு",
            "color": "green"
          }, {
            "name": "நினை",
            "color": "green"
          }, {
            "name": "மோப்பம்பிடி",
            "color": "green"
          }, {
            "name": "தேசம்",
            "color": "purple"
          }, {
            "name": "இடம்",
            "color": "purple"
          }, {
            "name": "பூமி",
            "color": "purple"
          }, {
            "name": "இராச்சியம்",
            "color": "purple"
          }, {
            "name": "நாட்டுப்புறம்",
            "color": "purple"
          }, {
            "name": "உலகம்",
            "color": "purple"
          }, {
            "name": "மருதநிலம்",
            "color": "purple"
          }, {
            "name": "பக்கம்",
            "color": "orange"
          }, {
            "name": "8 பதுமம்",
            "color": "blue"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "8 பதுமம்",
          "color": "maroon"
        }]
      };
      //var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
      //  .attr("class", "tooltip")
      // .style("opacity", 0)
      //.style("background",'#BCC5F7');
      function update(root) {
        var nodes = cluster.nodes(root);
        svg.selectAll("path.link").remove();
        svg.selectAll("g.node").remove();
        var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
          .data(cluster.links(nodes))
          .enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", diagonal)
          .style("stroke-width", "0.7px")
          .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d.color;
          })
          .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return d.target.color;
          });

        var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
          .data(nodes)
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          //    .attr("transform",
         "translate(" + radius / 2 + "," + radius / 2 + ")")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
          })

        node.append("circle")
          .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return d.color;
          })
          .style("fill", "none")
          .attr("r", 4.5).style("fill", function(d) {
            return d._children ? "red" : "#fff";
          }).on("click", click);

        node.append("text")
          .attr("class", "text")
          .style("stroke", "0.4px")
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            var r = // d3.select(this).node();
              d3.select("div#tooltip")
              .style("display", "inline")
              //    .style("top", (r.top-25) + "px")
              //  .style("top", 100 + "px")
              .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
              .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 80) + "px")
              //  .style("left", r.left + "px")
              // .style("left",  + "px")
              .style("position", "absolute")

            .text(d.t);
          })
          .on("mouseout", function() {
            d3.select("div#tooltip").style("display", "none")
          })

        .attr("dy", ".32em") //.style("fill", function(d) { return d.l; })

        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
            return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
          })
          .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return d.x < 180 ?
        "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-10)"; //270 10

          })

        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name

        });


      }
      update(data);

      function sortTree() {
        tree.sort(function(a, b) {
          return b.name.toLowerCase() < a.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
        });
      }

      // Sort the tree initially incase the JSON isn't in a sorted order.
      sortTree();

      function collapse(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d._children.forEach(collapse);
          d.children = null;
        }
      }

      data.children.forEach(collapse);
      update(data);


      function click(d) {
        if (!d.parent) {
          return;
        }

        if (!d.children)
          data.children.forEach(collapse);
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;

        }
        //  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", width);    
        update(data);
        if (d.parent) {
          //d3.selectAll("link").style("length",500);
          //d3.select("text") .style("fill", function(d) 
        { return d.l; })//.attr('transform', 'rotate(270)');
          //.attr("transform", function (d) {
          //  return d.x < 180 ? 
     "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-10)";   
          //  })



          return;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: According to everybody d3 is the ultimate tool for drawing graph, or any other data visualization. I guess I am the only one who thinks it's a piece of crap. I struggled a lot with these graph layouts too, and did not find the solution. Maybe the d3 community does not want to help, or it's just that nobody can really use these "tools".

Comment: yes..its difficult here to get the solution for the problems related to d3..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `click` function you need to collapse all nodes, if the clicked is opened.

Then open up the node you clicked like below:

```
function click(d) {
  //this collapse all the open nodes, if the clicked node is opened
  if(!d.children)
    data.children.forEach(collapse);
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(data);
}
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WCV6RURiMFwtSuLnDahE?p=preview)

Comment: thank u soo much Cyril... u solved 1st problem..is it possible to differentiate the open node by increasing its size or by making the opened parent node to red in color

Comment: Yes you can increase the size of the node or make it red. I think before you ask me how you can give it a try

Comment: i mean to differentiate open node from other nodes by size and make particular parent to red in colour

Comment: sure...i will try this and show my code soon...thank you

Comment: i have a circle even for the center parent..if i closed the whole children..again i cant able to open ..

Comment: This should fix it http://plnkr.co/edit/NNwluEHZM9SDOCmxoghS?p=info i am doing `  if (!d.parent){
    return;
  }` for checking if its root in that case it will not open.

Comment: i edited the above code..when i add the click function to this design  ,it opens the node,but close only when i drag the node circle..how should i use the click function here

Comment: i tried to run in js fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/6r550zne/4/  there is the problem in the way i add the external resource

Comment: @preetha please don't change the question. 
If you have new query post a new question, with a working fiddle.